# A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

C# codes are following

```
public partial class zoom1: PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public zoom1()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); //the erroe is shown here
    }

    private async void SetBackground1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (await LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync() == LockScreenRequestResult.Granted)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LockScreens/People/1.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
            LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri);
            MessageBox.Show("Your new lockscreen background has been set.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You said no, so I can't update your background.");
        }
    }
}
```

The error is generated after I added the click="" to the AppBarButton.
XAML codes are following

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" Opacity="0.5" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="Assets/Buttons/Check.png" Text="Set" Click="SetBackground1"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: Could you tell us on which line the error is occuring?  The error doesnt appear to match the code shown.

Comment: now I added both C# and XAML codes. When I remove the Click="" then this type of exception is not shown. But my AppBarButton doesn't work.

Comment: I'd have to work up a test to be sure, but I think it doesnt like the async signature on your `SetBackground1` method.

Comment: I created a new project for test with the same codes, but this time the exception isn't shown. I want to remove this exception in  my main project.

Comment: Please add the call stack

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the async? Also, the example in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbariconbutton%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) uses `EventArgs` rather than `RoutedEventArgs`, but I'm not sure that should cause the exception you're seeing.

Comment: LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync() is not working without async

Comment: Isolate the cause of the exception first, and then worry about refactoring to handle the async requirement.

Comment: I think the problem is with the SetBackground1 method

Comment: When I navigate from MainPage.xaml to Zoom1.xaml, the navigation is failed due to this exception. If I remove the Click="" from the Zoom1.xaml the navigation is done successfully.